# Can't see dynamic subview on iOS7(Working on iOS6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, addsubview

I have a custom TableViewCell. In the cell, I add two cross icons (using unicode) to both sides of the cell. when the user pans the cell, it will display the cross icon on the side.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // add a cross
        _crossLabel = [self createCueLabel];
        _crossLabel.text = @"\u274C";
        _crossLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        // none of the following code works
        [self insertSubview:_crossLabel aboveSubview:self];
        [self insertSubview:_crossLabel belowSubview:self];
        [self addSubview:_crossLabel];

        _crossLabel2 = [self createCueLabel];
        _crossLabel2.text = @"\u274C";
        _crossLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [self addSubview:_crossLabel2];

        // add a pan recognizer
        UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I used the code above to achieve that. And the _crossLabel did add to the Custom TableView Cell.

I used [Reveal App](http://revealapp.com) to check the layout of my iOS app
[image]
I can see _crossLabel has been added to my Cell. But I can't see the cross icon in my iOS 7 simulator. I have tried different methods to add the subView, but none of them works.

[image]

But it works perfectly on iOS6 and the layout is exactly same as iOS 7 when I check in Reveal App.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not tracked down the cause of this same crash in my app, but thanks for the shout-out to Reveal. Not come across it before, and it's awesome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure you are adding to the cell's contentView, `[self.contentView addSubView:_crossLabel2];` and not the cell itself. 
You will see when using Reveal and inspecting iOS7, that in a UITableViewCell UIKit has added/slipped in a UITableViewCellSCrollView above the cell view, so be careful with your `insertSubview:belowSubview` calls.
Also from your screenshot of the OutlineView of Reveal, the 'LocationCell' view is greyed out, which means it is hidden.

**Edit** just for future reference:
In iOS 7 the new UITableViewCellScrollView has it's 'clipToBounds' property set. It's a hack but if you [self.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO] . The superview is the UITableViewCellScrollView on iOS7 and the cell itself on iOS6

Comment: Thanks, I did try self.contentView and try it again, it doesn't work. Why the 'LocationCell' view is greyed out because I have removed the last cell from the table, the Reveal App caught the last layout before the animation. Apart from the last cell, the one above still visible. But when I pan it, it also doesn't display the cross icon.

Comment: What frame do the labels have when you inspect them? 
Regardless, you should always be adding to the cell's contentView. From the screenshot of Reveal you can see that the Labels are beneath the UITableViewCellContentView.

Comment: I added them to contentView but still can't see them, I found out if I added them inside the cell visible bounds, those cross icons are visible, if I added them to the edge of the cell, it would cut off. So  I think the problem is not addSubView method. The problem maybe iOS 7 will only render the cell from x(0 ~ 320).

Comment: the frame of one label is x=330.0, y=0.0, width= 50.0, height=44.0. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok, in iOS 7 the new UITableViewCellScrollView has it's 'clipToBounds' property set. Use Reveal to select the cells scroll view and in the inspector untick clipsToBounds. It's a hack but if you `[self.contentView.superview setClipsToBounds:NO]`, should work. The contentview's superview in iOS 6 is the cell itself, and in iOS 7 it's the cells scrollView

Answer (score -1):

No need to add on cells contentview. Simply you can access subview in iOS7 using

```
[[cell.subviews lastObject] subviews]
```